# How to correct update values in the for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a problem i am trying to solve, here is the description

```
def get_vectors(G):
adj = nx.adjacency_matrix(G)
x=np.matrix(np.eye(adj.shape[0]))
new=[]

 for i in range(n):
    x=0.5*(x.dot(adj)) +(1-0.5) * x
  new.append(np.array(x))
  
return new
```

Here i want the output of x to be input to only this part `0.5*(x.dot(adj)`) in the second iteration (just update the x values in the first part of the eqn and goes on).I don't need the result of each iteration, I only want result of the last iteration, however, in every loop, the result is the same.
How can I implement this simple code correctly?. Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: What does list 'new' include? And what is your expected output? Just a list of numbers that will represent the result of each equation?

Comment: 'new', contains result of the last iteration, My expected output is  the result of the second iteration @IoaTzimas

Comment: I may be a bit confused here, so tell me if I'm well off-base. Just based off your above description, your formula simplifies to x_1 = x_0 doesn't it? Hence each answer being the same?

Comment: Just as it expands to what? x_1 = .5*x_0 + .5*x_0 || 1 * x_0 || x_0?

Answer (score 0):

The following function takes x_0 as argument and n the number of iterations of the equation (or items to be added) you want to run (n). Result is a list where first 2 elements are x_0 and next elements follow the logic of your equation (0.5*x_0 + 0.5 *x_k) where k is the previous item:

```
def f(x_0, n):
    res=[x_0, x_0]
    for i in range(n):
        res.append(0.5*res[0]+0.5*res[-1])
    return res
```

If you know x_0 (let's say x_0=20) for 5 iterations result will be:

```
>>> f(20, 5)
[20, 20, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0]
```

Given the parameters you provided, all items will be equal with x_0 however this is a generic solution and it can be applied with any kind of equations, just amend the equation inside the function

Comment: why the output values in the list are 7?

Comment: We added 5 new items. We consider first 2 items as default. If you want 5 items in total, set n=3

Answer (score 0):

In your described problem, as has been commented by Osten Gibson, you appear to be halving a number and adding half of the original back on. Hence why each iteration is producing the same result.

If you are looking to half the previous number for each iteration, which is what I think you are trying to achieve, here is the solution:

```
array=[]
x = 1
limit = 2

for i in range(limit):
    x = 0.5*x
    array.append(x)

print(array[limit-1])
```

This program has a final output of 0.25 as 1/2 is 0.5 and then 0.5/2 is 0.25.

Comment: for i in range(n):
        x_1=0.5*(x_0) +0.5 * x_0)
                
        x_2= x_1+0.5 * x_0)     x_n= x_n-1+0.5 * x_0)   
 new.append(np.array(x_n))

Comment: This is what i want to achieve

Comment: @christinamuro Can you provide an input and what your expected outputs would be?

Comment: Unfortunately I am unfamiliar with the module in use and perhaps the maths you are trying to use here and will not be able to assist any futher.